# How to remove MessageBox Buttons?

Tags: c#, messagebox

I want to delete the buttons in a message box such as (yes, YesNo, OK ...), but not the close button. I found no way to do this unless deleting the parameter as well, but I can't do so since I need to add options parameters to my message box.

Comment: You need at least one button; it's part of the specification of a message box.  If you just want to display an informational message and, say, have it dismiss automatically after a few seconds without user intervention, you need to use something else besides a message box, probably just a simple form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree with @NDJ, the cleanest and most straight forward solution is to build your own message box based on a Form.  To modify the actual MessageBox would require lots of low level Windows APIs like in this [example](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18399/Localizing-System-MessageBox).  (That project is modifying the Text on the buttons.  You would need additional APIs to hide them; the MessageBox wouldn't resize though.)

*I'm not recommending you use the API approach...I'm just showing you how much effort and code it would take!

Answer (score 7):

I think your only option is to create a custom form which looks like a message box.

Answer (score 1):

According to [the C# API for MessageBox's](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.messageboxbuttons.aspx)

there is no member for `MessageBoxButtons.CLOSE` as you specify.  Do as NDJ says.

Comment: I meant by the that the red close button at the top.

Answer (score 1):

So if you mean to remove the close button. There's no way you can remove it unless you make new form. If u want to disable it. Copy this link below. I'm using it many times for the Close Button in the Message Box to be disabled.

```
    internal const int SC_CLOSE = 0xF060;           //close button's code in windows api
    internal const int MF_GRAYED = 0x1;             //disabled button status (enabled = false)
    internal const int MF_ENABLED = 0x00000000;     //enabled button status
    internal const int MF_DISABLED = 0x00000002;    //disabled button status

    [DllImport("user32.dll")] //Importing user32.dll for calling required function
    private static extern IntPtr GetSystemMenu(IntPtr HWNDValue, bool Revert);

    /// HWND: An IntPtr typed handler of the related form
    /// It is used from the Win API "user32.dll"

    [DllImport("user32.dll")] //Importing user32.dll for calling required function again
    private static extern int EnableMenuItem(IntPtr tMenu, int targetItem, int targetStatus);
```